# Add key and value of object based on Array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Iam working on a little project here, but i had some puzzle to do.

So i had a state of react the value is like this

```
const [dayValue, setDayValue] = useState({
    monday: false,
    tuesday: false,
    wednesday: false,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    saturday: false,
    sunday: false,
  });
```

And then i had an array like this

`const arrayDays = ['monday', 'wednesday', 'saturday'];`

What i want to do is to make all of my key object value that has the same value in `arrayDays` to change the value become `true`

I already tried some methods, one of it is i implement it on useEffect like this

```
    for (const x=0; x<arrayDays.length; x++) {
      for (const key in dayValue) {
        if (key === arrayDays[x]) {
          setDayValue({
            ...dayValue,
            [key]: true,
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

but its not working because setState hooks is a async function *CMIIW.
does anyone know hot to solve this puzzle ?

Comment: prepare Ur data and at last set it to state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the state using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) argument:

```js
setDayValue(dayValue => {
  const updated = {...dayValue};
  let needsUpdate = false;
  for (const day of arrayDays) {
    if (!(day in updated)) continue;
    updated[day] = true;
    needsUpdate = true;
  }
  return needsUpdate ? updated : dayValue;
});
```

Comment: Thankyou sir ! you are very fast respond and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = {...dayValue};
arrayDays.forEach( day => {
    if (temp[day] !== undefined) temp[day] = true;
})
setDayValue(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use immutable data structures when updating state in react. So this is what i would recommend

```
const arr = ['monday', 'wednesday', 'saturday'];

const updateDayValue = (arr) => {
  const updated = {
    ...dayValue,
    ...arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [cur]: true
      }
    }, {})
  }
  setDayValue(updated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written small piece of code for this one. I could have written one liner but I choose to split my logic in small pieces for you understanding

```
const updateState = () => {
    const stateClone = { ...dayValue };
    const keyValueMap = Object.keys(stateClone).map((key) => ({
      key,
      value: stateClone[key]
    }));
    const updatedState = keyValueMap.reduce(
      (acc, { key }) => ({ ...acc, [key]: arrayDays.includes(key) }),
      {}
    );
    setDayValue(updatedState);
  };
```

Also if you have any confusions you can go through this sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wood-gflskr?file=/src/App.js:350-699

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayDays.map(i => {
  Object.keys(dayValue).map(n => {
    if(i === n){
      setDayValue(daysN => {
        let days = {...daysN}
        days[n] = true
        return days
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.